# <img> messes with navbar-brand size | Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have the problem that in bootstrap if I put an image into an `<a class="navbar-brand">` it messes everything up.

```
<!-- Nav -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="img/bee-1000sqr.png" class="bnav-bee" style="padding-right: -100px;" />
        Bienenkamera
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form action="http://www.lugy-online.de/" method="get">
            <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Zurück zum LuGy</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- /Nav -->
```

The  inside the `<a class="navbar-brand">` causes the problem that the navbar-brand `<a>`-Tag is way to wide and my buttons are far too right and if I size the browser windows down the navbar-toggler is below the navbar-brand.

Can you help me?

```
.bnav-bee {
    max-width: 4%;
    margin-top: -10px;
}
```

I already tried to fix it with width-style(css) in the `<a>`-Tag and I tried to mess with the padding or margin. Neither of these worked.

Comment: You need to define what messes everything up means.  I guess you mean that the image is too wide for the design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify the width and the height of your image like in the example below.

And for spacing use the [native Bootstrap padding and margin classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/) such as `px-*` or `pl-*` or `mx-*` etc.

Here's the code snippet:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Nav -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://placehold.it/60" width="30" height="30" class="bnav-bee">
        Bienenkamera
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form action="http://www.lugy-online.de/" method="get">
            <button class="btn btn-primary my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Zurück zum LuGy</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
<!-- /Nav -->


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```